# How to extract region of interest with binary mask

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an original Chest X-Ray image (orig.jpg). I did manual segmentation with ITK-SNAP yielding this binary mask image (bmask.jpg):

[image]

To extract the lung region from background I run the following MATLAB code:

```
clear all;
clc;
IR=imread('orig.jpg');
im=imread('bmask.jpg');
ROI = IR;
ROI(im == 1) = 0;
ROI(im ~= 1) = 1;
SEG = IR.*ROI;
figure;
imshow(SEG);
imwrite(SEG,'SEG.jpg');
```

The result image:

[image]

I figured out since some pixels of binary mask inside the lung regions near the lung boundary has "1" value, the resulting image has some black dots near the lung boundary inside the lung regions. Also, in the resulting image, lung boundary has a zigzag pattern, not a smooth pattern as the binary mask. How can I fix these problems? Can anyone kindly help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the image you posted of the mask generated in Matlab (i.e. did you do `imshow(ROI)` to get that image)? Also, why not just use `SEG = IR .* (~boolean(im))` and get rid of `ROI` all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that the problem you have is because your jpg mask is NOT real binary image. Using jpg to store binary images is not very good idea, since due to compressive nature of jpegs, your mask will slightly deviate from binary image, especially at the edges.

To get real binary image from your jpeg mask you can try this:

```
Ibw = im2bw(rgb2gray(imread('mask.jpg')));
```

If this not help, when you generate your mask, do not use jpeg. Instead, use uncompressed (or with loss-less compression) tiff in gray-scale, or just stor it as binary matlab matrix in a file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
clear all;
clc;
IR=imread('orig.jpg');
im=imread('bmask.jpg'); %binary image
ROI = IR;
ROI(im == 0) = 0;
figure;
imshow(ROI);
```