# how to extract a region of interest from a binary image in python?

Tags: python, binary, image-segmentation, image-cropper

I have the image:

[image]

and the mask:

[image]

I want to crop the image with the mask using python. Something similar to
[How to extract region of interest with binary mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876290/how-to-extract-region-of-interest-with-binary-mask)
but with python instead of Matlab.
Thanks

Comment: I think it would be more helpful to provide two separate images without border/title for others to be able to reproduce your problem

Comment: @mozway thank you for your helpful comment. I have edited the question to make it clearer following your comment.

Comment: I think it was clear, what I meant is to provide **two images without border**, otherwise potential helper will need to have the burden of extracting each square before testing their potential answer. You should make it easy to answer.

Comment: @mozway Sorry for misunderstanding. Is it okay now?